# URL clintonbegin.com redirects to 127.0.0.1

Tags: http, dns

I was reading [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) and when i clicked on an link with the name "Dwemthy’s Array in Java" which pointed to http://clintonbegin.com/dwemthy/ i was SHOCKED to see a website i administer and its legit certificate.

Using ping and nslookup for clintonbegin.com on different machines answered with 127.0.0.1
What calmed me down and peaked my interest was the answer of ssllabs.com (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=clintonbegin.com) which said "SSL Report: clintonbegin.com (127.0.0.1) [...] Assessment failed: IP address is from private address space (RFC 1918)".

Several DNS checks of "clintonbegin.com" using online tools also point to 127.0.0.1.

Is that even possible or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DNS server can report any IP for any host. The domain in question just configured their DNS to return 127.0.0.1 for that record.

The link you link to is HTTP, not HTTPS. So it just a request to your local webserver, on port 80.

Depending on which web application framework and server you're running there, that redirects you to https://127.0.0.1. Or perhaps your browser had that redirect cached, or you have reported with a HSTS response somewhere in the past.

So: there's nothing on the hand.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you can configure a DNS-Record to point to 127.0.0.1